# Raspberry Pi MPI3508 touchscreen won't run X?

Tags: touchscreen

I've got a Raspberry Pi 4 running the latest Raspberry Pi OS (Bookworm). It's been running great, and today I attached my MPI3508 3.5" touch display. Before installing drivers it was working great as an HDMI display, but when I ran the driver install according to these instructions, I'm getting a blank screen on boot:

http://www.lcdwiki.com/3.5inch_HDMI_Display-B

The Pi does boot - I can get in via SSH - but it looks like the X server isn't starting.

I can also successfully run a VNC server.

I noticed that the install script installs an older version of xserver-xorg-input-evdev - apt-get upgrade brought it up to date.

I've tried running the "reset" script - ./LCD-hdmi - and am getting the same results.

Can anybody suggest anything that could help me get my display working?

Comment: Bookworm doesn't use X. Try reading the release notes.

Comment: Maybe: the X server doesn't start b/c there is no X server installed w/ bookworm on RPi 4. bookworm on RPi 4 & 5 uses the new Wayland, whereas older Pi hardware remains on X. You should read [this news post](https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/bookworm-the-new-version-of-raspberry-pi-os/) as it has information that may help you move forward.

Comment: You should be able to run X if you want/need to; I'd use `raspi-config` to set it for non-graphical boot, then try `startx` (that's in the `xinit` package, if it wasn't already added by the installer you ran).  You may just get a black screen with a white "X" cursor in it that should respond to a mouse (and hopefully the touchscreen); that's the minimal X install to which you need to add a window manager and desktop environment. The current default GUI may or may not work w/ X instead of Wayland.

Comment: Thanks all for your replies. I’m now working on getting this thing running having switched to X. Looks like this is a new enough challenge that there’s not much info on it yet. Here’s the only thing I’ve found so far: https://area-51.blog/2023/10/12/getting-the-raspbery-pi-official-touchscreen-to-work-with-raspios-bookworm/